# I do not know how to plot the probability distribution of outcomes of some code in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability-distribution

I have created a program that simulates the throwing of dice 100 times. I need help with adding up the results of the individual dice and also how to plot the probability distribution of outcomes.

This is the code I have:

```
sample(1:6, size=100, replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, what you've done is sample the dice throws (note I've added a line setting the seed for reproducibility:

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1:6, size=100, replace = TRUE)
```

The simple command to "add[] up the results of the individual dice" is `table()`:

```
table(x)
# x
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 17 16 20 14 18 15
```

Then, to "plot the probability distribution of outcomes," we must first get that distribution; luckily R provides the handy `prop.table()` function, which works for this sort of discrete distribution:

```
prop.table(table(x))
# x
#    1    2    3    4    5    6 
# 0.17 0.16 0.20 0.14 0.18 0.15
```

Then we can easily plot it; for plotting PMFs, my preferred plot type is `"h"`:

```
y <- prop.table(table(x))
plot(y, type = "h", xlab = "Dice Result", ylab = "Probability")
```

[image]

#### Update: Weighted die

`sample()` can easily used to simulate weighted die using its `prob` argument. From `help("sample")`:

> Usage
>   sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
>
> Arguments
>   [some content omitted]
>   prob      a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled.

So, we just add your preferred weights to the `prob` argument and proceed as usual (note I've also upped your sample size from 100 to 10000):

```
set.seed(123)
die_weights <- c(4/37, rep(6/37, 4), 9/37)
x <- sample(1:6, size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = die_weights)
(y <- prop.table(table(x)))
# x
#      1      2      3      4      5      6 
# 0.1021 0.1641 0.1619 0.1691 0.1616 0.2412 
plot(y, type = "h", xlab = "Dice Result", ylab = "Probability")
```

[image]

Comment: Would you know how to simulate a loaded dice? One where the probability to roll a: 1 is 4/37, 2/3/4/5 is 6/37, 6 is 9/37?

Comment: @user11301096 Sure -- see the edited answer! It sounds like you're an R beginner. While it won't help you find the functions you need, you'll need to get really well acquainted with the `help()` function (or equivalently `?`), because it does help you learn about the functions you have heard of. Here, looking at `help("sample")` would have been the key: It teaches you about the `prob` argument, which is what you use to accomplish probability weighting.